# Apache2 "pseudo" doc root

Tags: apache, htaccess, apache2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have several folders in my /www folder that contain various applications. To keep things organized, I keep them in their own folders -- this includes my base application.

Examples:

1. phpmyadmin = /www/phpmyadmin
2. phpvirtualbox = /www/phpvirtualbox
3. root domain site = /www/Landing

The reason I segregate all of my sites is that I actively develop on some of these (my root site) and when I publish via Visual Studio, I choose to delete prior to upload - if I put the Landing page in the base folder, it would be devastating for me.

My goal is that when I go to www.example.com - I go to my page.  If I go to www.example.com/phpmyadmin, it does not work because of this in the Apache2 folder:

```
<Location "/"> # Error is the "/"
  Allow from all
  Order allow,deny
  MonoSetServerAlias domain
  SetHandler mono
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
</Location>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
</IfModule>
```

If I change the location to say "/Other", then the base site is broken, and the aliases are restored for the other sites.  If it is "/", then the base site works and no aliases work.

What could I do to allow it to treat my /www/Landing as my webroot, but when I go to an alias, it GOES to the alias.

Edit: Added in the default VirtualHost info.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 days"

  MonoServerPath domain "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
  MonoDebug domain true
  MonoSetEnv domain MONO_IOMAP=all
  MonoApplications domain "/:/var/www/Landing"

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) /Landing/$1 [L]


#Need to watch what the Location is set to. Can cause issues for alias
<Location "/">
  Allow from all
  Order allow,deny
  MonoSetServerAlias domain
  SetHandler mono
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
</Location>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
</IfModule>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with Mono, but it seems like the other sites should work if you leave the location as `/` but only the base site would work if you set the location as `/Landing`.

What most people would do is simply leave the location as `/` and use mod_rewrite to map non-phpmyadmin or -phpvirtualbox requests to the `/Landing/` directory, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /Landing/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Added this to the virtualhost file and still the same.